# VPN issues on web browsing

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm using Maverick and this is the setup:

Our router connects us to the company's VPN through which we can access some internal websites. I have to connect also to a customer's VPN in order to use remote desktop and their websites daily.

This customer has a web interface to connect to its VPN, it launches a Java App which signs us in and lets us use the services on their network.

When I do this, I loose access to my company's VPN services (websites) in all browsers. This doesn't happen in the rest of the (Windows) boxes, and I'm the only one using GNU/Linux on the office.

Right now, I log out of the customer's VPN to access the company's services, but I'm sure there's some solution so that I can use both VPNs together.

Answer (score 1):

It would help to know what VPN your customer is using.

It sounds as though there's split-tunneling going on with the Windows clients in your office--only the traffic specific to the customer site is traveling through the customer VPN, leaving the rest of the traffic to go where your company router sends it. It would seem that this isn't happening on your Maverick system.

You might find an answer if you figured out what VPN the customer was using, and looked for information around split-tunneling, Linux, and that particular VPN product.

Answer (score 0):

What are the ip ranges the vpns are allocating for routing? It might well be that both are the same (i.e. 192.168.*) and because of that you can only access one at a time.

Comment: I have no clue. How can I find out?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. Can you please explain in details how we can find out what is preventing us the in accessing both the VPN and the public sites at the same time? Step by step guidance will help in a big way to solve the problem.

Comment: @Fernando: `ifconfig` on commandline